# How Do I Pass A Schema Value With Units From Apostrophe 3?

Tags: frontend, apostrophe-cms, apostrophe

I want to give the user the ability to customize border-radius on my component (widget) in ApostropheCMS.

I have written the following schema for the same:

```
borderRadiusValue: {
          label: 'Border Radius value',
          type: 'range',
          unit: 'px',
          min: 0,
          max: 50,
          step: 1,
          def: 0,
          if: {
            havingBorderRadius: true
          }
        },
```

I want to apply the value from `borderRadiusValue` as inline style in my html so that the it looks something like this `style = "border-radius: {{widget.borderRadiusValue}} 0 0 {{widget.borderRadiusValue}}`

However, for `borderRadiusValue` as 50px, I only get style applied as `style = "border-radius: 50 0 0 50`. Instead, I want it to be `style = "border-radius: 50px 0 0 50px`. Does ApostropheCMS have this feature? How do I go about implementing this?

[Here is a link to range fields in A3](https://v3.docs.apostrophecms.org/reference/field-types/range.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`range` fields have a numeric value, without units. So the simplest way to do what you want is:

```
style = "
  border-radius:
    {{widget.borderRadiusValue}}px
    0
    0
    {{widget.borderRadiusValue}}px
"
```

Note the "px" after emitting each number.

Comment: yes, this is the implementation I have went ahead with. Maybe in the future it would be a cool implementation to add the unit automatically to the emitted value :D

Can we open a PR for this on the A3 github?

Comment: I would not really recommend it because it makes more sense to output it in the context of the template (e.g. where the rest of this CSS is being output). From Apostrophe's point of view it is just an integer. Moving things like the units or the CSS property name into the field configuration would really just be moving part of the template into the field configuration, which would be a redundant implementation of templates.

Comment: However do check out the palette module if you're doing this kind of thing a lot:

https://apostrophecms.com/extensions/palette-3